# Which cipher suites with AES cipher provide forward secrecy?

Tags: cryptography, encryption, tls, key-exchange

Does standard AES with RSA (reported by Opera as `TLS v1.0 256 bit AES (1024 bit RSA/SHA)`) provide [perfect forward secrecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_forward_secrecy)?

Which SSL3.0 and TLS1.0 ciphers do provide forward secrecy?

Which ciphers in openssl provide forward secrecy *and* are regarded as secure?

Comment: Those cipher suites have **DHE** or **ECDHE** in their names.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cipher suites which provide perfect forward secrecy are those which use a Diffie-Hellman key exchanged, *signed* by the server -- but the server key may be of type RSA. Consider [the TLS standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-75): there are two cipher suites which use AES with a 256-bit key, SHA-1 for integrity check, and a RSA server key:

- `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA`
- `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA`

Only the latter provides perfect forward secrecy. In the former, the key exchange is done by encrypting a random value with the RSA server keys, something which can be unraveled later on by an attacker who could steal a copy of the server private key.

Information provided by Opera does not seem to be sufficient to distinguish between those two cipher suites.

Comment: Note, apart from standard DHE suites there are also the elliptic curve versions named [...]_ECDHE_[...].

Opera might not give you all the information but maybe it allows to disable the ciphersuites without forward secrecy. According to Google you can do that in Tools \ Preferences \ Advanced Tab \ Security Item \ Security Protocols \ Details. It is possible that some SSL sites do not work anymore after this, but to my knowledge DHE is very common.

Comment: Opera does distinguish between them, DH versions are reported as `TLS v1.0 256 bit AES (1024 bit DHE_RSA/SHA)`

Comment: @pepe: I'm more interested in making sure that my server provides only ciphers with perfect forward secrecy

Comment: Well then that's no problem, just set the ciphers we named in your server configuration. For compatibility you might want to set them as preferred ciphers and still allow other mechanisms depending on what the client supports. Preferred use of DHE may even be the default already, I'm not sure..

Comment: @Hubert: in TLS, the client announces what cipher suites it supports (ordered list: preferred client suite comes first), and then the server chooses the cipher suite that will be used. Normally, the suites that the server will use can be configured (it depends on the server TLS implementation). Also, traditionally, the server follows the client order of preference, but, then again, some servers may be configured to enforce their order of preference.

Comment: @pepe: Unfortunately DH isn't really common, probably because IE doesn't support it.

Comment: @Hubert: IE supports DHE, with a 'E' as "ephemeral" (the DH parts are dynamically generated and the server signs them; the server certificate contains the signature key, often RSA-based). What IE does not support is "static DH" in which the server certificate contains a Diffie-Hellman public key directly.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, I was thinking about DHE and I'm quite sure that at least IE6 and Windows XP libraries don't support DHE, newer versions or newer versions working on Vista or 7 may support it.

Comment: @Hubert: If you have to use Windows for accessing the Internet, try using a version that is not 10 years old. MS implemented significant structural security advances since XP.

Comment: @pepe: please, don't troll. If you're not trolling: it's still supported by MS and it's still used by millions of people. I can't force them to change the OS. If I want my site to be accessible by them (that's "only" 10% of traffic, most of which are corporate clients) I have to allow usage of 3DES or RC4 without DH.

Comment: @Hubert: I forgot that you were talking about server side, that obviously limits your options. For intranet and client side I stand by my point. The extended XP security support was not originally intended by MS and if you have to use Windows, you should not use such antiques. I only use XP for "App-VMs" since it is much smaller.

Comment: @Hubert: IE6 _does_ support DHE cipher suites; I tested it with a Win2000 client (if it works with Win2k it should work with XP). However, it can use it only if the server key has type DSS (not RSA), and, moreover, it has a bug which makes it fail if the server sends an empty record (recent versions of OpenSSL send empty records as a workaround for a potential but esoteric weakness related to CBC; IE 6.0 chokes on empty records) but OpenSSL has an option to avoid empty records: SSL_OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS. See: http://www.openssl.org/~bodo/tls-cbc.txt

Comment: @Thomas: So it both does and doesn't. Considering that standard DSS limits key sizes to 1024bit, the DHE in IE6 is unusable in any secure deployment. Also, don't later versions of IE (or system crypto library) also support DHE *only* with DSS by a chance?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the traditional Diffie-Hellman cipher suites you can also use those based on Elliptic Curve DH key exchange, they provide Perfect Forward Secrecy as well.

Suitable ciphers are listed in [RFC4492](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4492.txt).

Comment: Curious why this was downvoted? Is it wrong that EC can provide  PFS?

Comment: @AviD: Wondering too. No, it's the DH in ECDH that provides the same goodies that DH does, PFS being one of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5474/forward-secrecy-with-https-and-aes#comment8871_5476

Comment: Elliptic Curve DH *is not* Diffie Hellman. The former uses elliptic curves, the latter integer logarithms. And considering that the ECDH is at least 10 times faster than DH, it's good to know of its existence.

Comment: @HubertKario You've got to be kidding me? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14731/what-is-ecdhe-rsa ?

Comment: @emboss: ECDH is using elliptic curves, EDH is using modulo arithmetic multiplicative group of integers. They achieve the same result (forward secrecy) but using slightly different methods. In effect, ECDH is fast, EDH is not. This difference alone warrants voting up this answer. (And the previous comment was supposed to be an answer to @AndreyBotalov)

Comment: @HubertKario OK, now I get it! Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: "The ECDHE_ECDSA and ECDHE_RSA key exchange algorithms provide forward secrecy protection in the event of server key compromise, while ECDH_ECDSA and ECDH_RSA do not." This answer doesn't mention that and says about ECDH in general.

Comment: @HebertKario "No, it's the DH in ECDH that provides the same goodies that DH does" is also incorrect. Either DHE or ECDHE is needed. DH and ECDH don't provide forward secrecy