# How widely used is Elliptic Curve Cryptography?

Tags: ecc

I would like to know how widely ECC is being used today (or has been used in recent years). How do I find data about this? Also, what are good metrics for quantifying this?

Comment: See also [How widely deployed is TLS with cipher ECDHE?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/59459/how-widely-deployed-is-tls-with-cipher-ecdhe)

Comment: Could you make your question more specific?

Comment: ECDH is very common, and ECDSA (sometimes caled EdDSA) is also becoming more popular for PKI.

Answer (score 1):

The best source you probably have, apart from doing a broad scan yourself, is to check the [Certificate Transparency logs](https://crt.sh). Only a few days ago, someone [tweeted a statistic](https://twitter.com/erbbysam/status/861713266128584704) from those logs (I could not find a better source for it than twitter, so take it with a grain of salt).

Comment: Elliptic curve Diffie Hellman (ECDHE) can be used with RSA certificates. So the certificate would show as RSA in the CT logs, but for setting up the connection ECC would be used.

Comment: That is correct, thanks for pointing it out @Sjoerd. The question is a very broad one, hard to figure out what the OP really wants to know.