# RSA key exchange is obsolete. Enable an ECDHE-based cipher suite

Tags: rsa, key, exchange

If what this says is what I think, does that mean the connection could be compromised and or vulnerable to MitM &/or other attacks? Cert shows to be good, but there is this "RSA key exchange is obsolete. Enable an ECDHE-based cipher suite", which makes me question if its legit..?

Comment: related to https://security.stackexchange.com/q/14731/5470

Answer (score 3):

It means that the cryptography from the certificate is breakable - [the ROBOT attack is a good write up on how](https://robotattack.org/).  ECDHE uses elliptic-curve cryptography, which is faster, uses less data for the same level of security, and relies on newer mathematical techniques (although it's not necessarily a good thing...but as a quick aside ECs were needed for solving Fermat's last theorem and that only happened in 1994).

So yes, it's a legit warning.  It's probably just popping up because the site hasn't used a ECDHE cipher.  Which is far from ideal, but if everybody followed best practices I'd be out of a job.